# Copper pipe for brine water block ice system

Tags: refrigeration

I am looking to replace copper pipes from a brine water block ice system .
The pipes needed are 5/8 but wonder what wall thickness it should be.
They should be thick enought to withstand 60 psi pressure.

[image: old pipes that are in the tank]

[image: toptech]

Comment: So, a good start would be to state the pressure...

Comment: Pressure is around 60 psi

Comment: And add the information to the question properly - don’t leave it to rot in a comment.

Comment: Standard domestic copper pipes have a pressure rating, I think it's 160psi but I could be wrong. Pretty much any pipe you can find with a pressure rating should work since this is lower than most peoples water pressure.

Comment: Will the toptech tube with a wall thickness of 0.031" work?

Comment: They are tubing , not pipes. Cupro nickel would have better corrosion resistance.

Answer (score 0):

The dimensions are about the same as 1/2 copper tubing used for water systems in the USA. Your typical box store would probably stock the 1/2" tubing. They will withstand your pressure without a problem. The tricky part is the 180 bends. Those can probably be purchased from your local refrigeration supplier. The joints look like they were either silver soldered or brazed. For a chart showing this goto: https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/cts-copper-tubing-sizes-d_2112.html

Answer (score 0):

Based on the dimensions the TopTech copper tube your are evaluating appears to have a slightly thicker wall than "1/2 inch Type M"

[image]

This graph was found on page 21 of the [copper tube handbook](http://www-eng.lbl.gov/%7Eshuman/NEXT/MATERIALS&COMPONENTS/Pressure_vessels/copper_tube_handbook.pdf).

Since the tubing is bendable it is the "Annealed" type.

Looking up the [copper tube working pressure on engineering toolbox](https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/copper-tubes-dimensions-pressure-d_84.html) gives a working pressure of 420psi. Your application's 60psi plus the dynamic head of the pump will be well within limits.

[image]

The downside of using bendable tubing instead of pipe is that you are going to have a hard time getting nice straight runs and getting it to look nice. For the most part if you have sufficient gaps the thermal performance wont be an issue. But if the coils must support the weight of ice or other loads you may want to consider drawn pipe instead of annealed tube.

The upside of tube is that you don't have to solder the 180degree turns at the end. Just use a [tubing bender sized for 5/8 Inch OD](https://www.lesman.com/364fha10).